# Are there any wrapped ERC20 tokens that are privacy coins?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, privacy, monero, wrapped-tokens

ERC20 tokens by itself are not private as anyone can see everyone's balance. But a wrapped token for a privacy coin like Monero or Zcash can be anonymous when converted from the wrapped version. Does anything like this exist yet as of OCT 2020?

Comment: I'm not sure how useful such would be as it loses all privacy when it's moved around in Ethereum...

Comment: https://tornado.cash/ is not exactly what you are looking for but is what's currently available. [tag:tornado-cash]

Comment: And here we go, going against the nature and purpose of blockchain: making privacy stuff on a tool that's supposed to be open/public. And above all, coins, tokens. Lets make money ! Sorry, but I'm pissed that blockchain just became only a stock exchange 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, LOKI now available on UniswapProtocol

- Swap wLOKI <-> USDT : https://uniswap.info/pair/0xf00fe8deba4fe94642846a91568f43bd93333ffb
- Swap wLOKI <-> LOKI : https://wloki.chainflip.io
- https://loki.network/